# No internet connection in Guest Machine

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, virtualbox

I'm using Windows 7 as a host and as a guest, and I can't get the guest to have internet access. At home when I'm connected to my wi-fi network the internet access in the guest works just fine (using NAT), but when I connect to the wireless network in my workplace, using the same settings the guest has no internet access. I also used a bridge connection to no avail.

Any idea about what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe internet access is limited at work, maybe through MAC address filtering.

Comment: But I have even generated a new mac address for the NAT in the virtualbox manager, wouldn't that be enough?

Comment: Not if this MAC is not on the list of accepted ones in the router at work - still assuming there is such filtering. You can test this by connecting from the host. It can also be that your nic is not directly supported and you need to install extensions pack in Guest OS.

Comment: As I said this is working just fine when I'm at home and as for the mac filtering, my mac hasn't been registered in the work network and the host has internet access still, they don't do that filtering. Also, I've got the extensions pack installed. Thanks

Comment: That's irrelevant information. You say guest OS cannot reach internet, what about host?

Comment: The internet is working just fine in the host and the guest can ping the host.

Comment: While at work, the host reach internet, but not does guest, while at home, both guest and host reach internet. In both cases the internet path is through a Wireles router, is all this correct?

Comment: Yes Frank, in both cases I'm using the wireless interface.

Comment: Maybe (aka a guess) is a comment not an answer.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)

Comment: @Marco I give up. You're not answering my questions.

Comment: Which question did I not answered? Yes your assumption is correct and in both cases I am indeed using a Wireless router :)

Comment: I set the guest machine to use the same proxy as the host and it worked... I'm just not sure why I need to do it since the guest is using the client connection settings.

Answer (score 1):

Find the point of failure by doing smaller tests and expanding out to the full test.

First ping self, then the host, then the dns servers, gateway, etc. and then eventually some internet server.

Don't assume dns works unless you tested it. Also don't assume ping isn't blocked. Ping via IP if dns doesn't work. Or use curl or a web browser to test if ping (icmp echo request) is blocked.

Use tcpdump or similar tool on the host at every step of the way to see what is going on. (such things are way easier on linux... 3rd party stuff should work on windows, but are a hassle)